# Dataset filtering by single column and multiple factors

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

this is probably a simple question but I could not find a solution even after scouting for Q&A for a quite long time and reading all the cheat-sheets  I could find.

Let's say I have the following dataset

```
participant <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3,3 ,4,4)
trial <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4) 
page <- c(1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 2, 1, 2) 
test <- data.frame(participant, trial, page)
```

I want to remove from my dataset specific trials and/or pages within trials, for specific participants.

So, for example, let's assume I want to remove from my dataset Trial 2 and Page 2 for Participant 1 only.

I tried this, but it removes the participant completely

```
test <- dplyr::filter(test, participant != "1" & trial != "2" & page != "2")
```

How can I remove only values in relation to another value?
Thanks!

Comment: please keep in mind I do not want to create new smaller datasets with fewer columns or raws, as my dataset is huge and very complex and needs to be complete.

Comment: and to be more specific, i need to remove Page 2 OF Trial 2 OF Participant 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr::filter` only keeps rows for which the provided condition is true. Your thinking was correct that a simple way to do this is to make a conditional statement that matches the row you want to remove, and then invert it to select the other rows. The problem is the way inverting `==` to `!=` interacts with the AND operator `&`

You give the condition `participant != "1" & trial != "2" & page != "2"` which is true only if ALL the following conditions are true (since you used `&`):

- participant is not 1
- trial is not 2
- page is not 2

So if a row doesn't meet ANY of those criteria (for example, every row where `participant == 1`), it will be removed

---

Since you want to do is make a conditional statement that matches the rows you want to remove, and then invert it by using the NOT operator `!` around the entire statement in parentheses:

```
dplyr::filter(test, !(participant == 1 & trial == 2 & page == 2))

  participant trial page
1           1     1    1
2           2     2    2
3           2     3    5
4           3     4    6
5           3     2    2
6           4     3    1
7           4     4    2
```